# how to filter array via dynamic filter selected via rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

i have an array of products here it is

```
  let products=[
    {id:1,category:[23,34],subcategory:[45,67],company:[56,78]}
    {id:2,category:[46,19],subcategory:[89,645],company:[16,88]}
]
```

and here is my dynamic filter array which i have to apply

```
 let filter=[
     {key:"category",values:[19]}
     {key:"company",values:[88,16]}
   ]
```

how can i dynamically filter the products array via **rxjs**
here is my code which is working for only one filter , but i need for dynamicacally coming more then 1

here is my code for 1 filter i gave the type e.g

```
  type="category"
  values=[18,19]
 products.pipe(
            flatMap(response => response),
            filter(
                (product: any) => {
                    
                    return product[type].find((catnum) => values.includes(catnum))
                }
            ), toArray()
        ).subscribe(data => {}
```

Comment: So products is a stream of several products, not a stream of a products array. How about the filter? Is it also a stream of filter entries? Is it a stream of a filter array or is it a plain object?

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood you, you want to filter products array using if some of the condition in **filter** array is matched and this **filter** array may change over the time. 
First of all, you should use **map** operator to modify products stream. And inside map operator you have to filter products which pass the condition.

```
this.products$
      .pipe(
        map((products) => {
          return products.filter((product) => {
            return this.filters.some((filter) => this.isProductMeetFilterConditions(product, filter))
          })
        })
      )

private isProductMeetFilterConditions(product: Product, filter: Filter): boolean {
    return filter.values.some((value) => {
      return product[filter.key].includes(value)
    })
  }
```

I have implemented it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-akenvn?file=src/app/app.component.ts), you can open console and see filtered results

Comment: its working fine , but its return product if any of one filter is match , if should not return product if any of filter is not match i tried this on your code and its returning product

[{key:"category",values:[19]},{key:"company",values:[18]}];

its should not

Comment: If product should satisfy all filters, then just change this.filters.some to this.filters.every