# RXJS: Create and chain a dynamic array of filters

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to create a service that can dynamically filter a stream of Record<string, unkonwn> by it's keys. The idea is I can call like an "addFilter" on the service and pass an observable with a filter which is then stored in an array of observables in the service. Then when the observable of Records notifies in the service, it should enumerate all of the filtered observables in the array and remove them from the stream.

I'm probably WAY off base here, but this is where I am at right now, just creating the actual chain of filters.

```
  chainFilters(filters: Observable<Record<string, unknown>>[]) {
    return (source$: Observable<Record<string, unknown>>) => {
      var observables = filters.reduce(
        (
          acc: Observable<Record<string, unknown>>[],
          value: Observable<Record<string, unknown>>
        ) => {
          return acc.concat(value);
        }, []);
      return source$.pipe(???);
    }
  }
```

I thought about returning concat(observables) in this case but it says concat is deprecated.  No clue where to go from here.

The best example I could find of something remotely similar is [here](https://gist.github.com/zebulonj/c9468379ef40221160c6) but that doesn't work with RxJS in angular, I'm a little confused about how to translate that.

EDIT: Project is using RxJS 6.5.5

At the request of @maxime1992, am going to try to explain the problem a little more to help with understanding...

So I have a stream of Record<string, unknown> coming from a dynamic array of form fields, form groups, and form arrays, all generated with JSONSchema using Formly that combine to build a multi step wizard of sorts. That in and of itself is not important to except to say that the forms themselves cannot be changed, they just emit the Record<string, unknown> objects. Nested form groups may emit records that contain multiple child "Records."

The problem comes in that although most of those "Records" are valid against the original JSON schema from the db, others are added virtually based on a json config that is merged with the schema before generating the form. Those wont validate against the json schema in the database, and need to get 'plucked' (for lack of a better word), OUT of of the stream before the remainder of the stream is sent to the server to save. So basically there would be ONE subscriber for each plucked record, which would be a separate service that would inject the main service where the stream is coming from, and call an "addFilter" function on that service, with a filter defined by the subscriber. This would put a filter into the array of filters on the main service. Each filter removes the record being filtered from the main stream to used by the subscribing service, and lets the others go through unimpeded.

I am not needing to know how to do all the services, I just am having trouble figuring out how to structure the filter, in a way that can be chained via the array of filters, to remove those records from the main stream.

I hope that helps describe the problem a little more...

Comment: why not use `concatWith` which replaces `concat` ?

Comment: Can you add a usage example ?

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos Project is still using rxjs 6.5.5, which doesnt support concatWith yet as far as I can tell.

Comment: @serrulien Im not sure how I can add usage examples as the whole thing doesnt really work yet. Although, the link provided in the last paragraph pretty much highlights what I am trying to do though. Just imagine those observables being added via the addFilter function in a service instead of being applied manually.

Comment: take a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63503933/11900833), maybe you'll find something usefull

Comment: You've described a lot what you're trying to achieve through explaining code. Which is hard to understand IMO as you've said it yourself, it doesn't really work so far. Could you edit your post to explain what you're trying to achieve, if possible with a minimal idea of what you want? I'm happy to help but I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve :)

Comment: Do you basically want to be able to filter a stream based on a stream of filters themselves coming overtime? Maybe a schema or try to reformulate would help

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Reading through.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I'm sorry I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve :( Maybe if you try doing a schema on https://excalidraw.com and post the picture in your post that'd help?

Comment: Just imagine you have a stream of key value pairs, and you need to filter it by certain keys, you pluck those out of the stream, and the rest of the stream goes on uninterrupted. I am absolutely horrible at flow charts lol, but I can try that. Will have something up by this afternoon.

Comment: "and you need to filter it by certain keys". Are those keys static or coming from a stream themselves?

Comment: The keys being filtered are defined by the subscriber that is interested in those keys. So imagine the subscribing service calling something like mainStreamService.addFilter("keyName", filter) with the filter simply being a monotype operator function or something. Then in the main stream service, when the main record stream notifies it just enumerates through all the filters that were added and removes the record that match the keys in the array of filters. I am just not understand how I can chain a dynamic array of operator functions like that.

Comment: Can your filters be represented by a predicate function? Can you provide a service for components to add such predicates to some collection? If you have an array of predicates it's easy to chain them in an observable filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve exactly but I'm going to give it a go and you can give feedback if that's what you expect. Maybe it'll be easier to discuss around some code.

First, let's talk API without any details on how the `MainStreamService` is implemented behind the scene. Does that look ok to you?

Assuming that the initial data is:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3,
  "d": 4,
  "f": 5
}
```

And we have the following code:

```
const mainStreamService = new MainStreamService();

mainStreamService.mainDataFiltered$
  .pipe(
    map(x => JSON.stringify(x, null, 2)),
    tap(console.log)
  )
  .subscribe();

const dynamicFilter$$ = new Subject<Record<string, unknown>>();

mainStreamService.addFilter(dynamicFilter$$);

dynamicFilter$$.next({ b: null, c: null, d: null });
```

It outputs 2 results:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3,
  "d": 4,
  "f": 5
}
```

(the initial data)

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "f": 5
}
```

(the data after the filter was applied)

In the hope that's pretty much what you're looking for, here the implementation I've got:

```
import {
  of,
  map,
  Observable,
  Subject,
  combineLatest,
  BehaviorSubject
} from 'rxjs';
import { mergeAll, scan, shareReplay, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

class MainStreamService {
  // this is simply a mock, push the data you want in here
  public mainData$: Observable<Record<string, unknown>> = of({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    f: 5
  });

  // a behavior subject will let you get the last emitted value
  // if you subscribe to it later on, which is what we want here
  // important thing to note, it's a behavior subject of observable...
  // so when we start modifying that stream (using `pipe`, we'll consider it to be an observable... of observables!)
  // we'll see how to deal with that in second
  private filters$$: BehaviorSubject<
    Observable<Record<string, unknown>>
  > = new BehaviorSubject(of({}));

  // using the filters defined above, we want to go from an observable of observables... to an observable
  // whenever you need to do that, you have to think "higher order operator"
  // a higher order operator will let you extract an observable of observable, into an observable
  // it's not as complicated as it sounds and if you're familiar with
  // the observables such as `switchMap`, `mergeMap` (or `flatMap`), `concatMap`, `exhaustMap`, ...
  // then you won't struggle to understand that concept because it's the same thing except that it'll extract
  // the values from the inner observable and put them back into the main observable
  // the operators that are available to you are [`switchAll`][1], [`mergeAll`][1], [`concatAll`][1], [`exhaustAll`][1], ...
  // and as you guessed it, they have the same behavior as the ones you know already with the name ending by `map` instead of `all`
  private excludedKeys$: Observable<Record<string, true>> = this.filters$$.pipe(
    // here I've used merge all to make sure that we listen to all of them in parallel otherwise if we used `switchAll` for example, we would unsubscribe from the old filter observable before subscribing to the new one
    mergeAll(),
    // finally, scan is a life savior! If you're used to the `reduce` function in Javascript it should click straight away. If not, here's the deal: 
    // `scan` will let you accumulate values over time and you have to specify an initial value
    // when working with observables, you want to have immutable data, always
    // therefore, I start of by passing the second argument of the function a new object `{}`
    // whenever we receive a new filter (object), we read the keys
    // and I do a `reduce` on the array (pure JS here, not reduce from rxjs!) to loop over all the keys and assign a new value for each of those: `true`
    // note on this: I could use an array here but as we're only interested in knowing if a key is black listed, we're better off putting them into 
    // an array that we'd have to iterate on all the time and we rather use an equivalent of a `Set`... Except that `Set` isn't immutable. So I'm using an object to represent a dictionary
    scan((acc, obj) => {
      const keys = Object.keys(obj);

      return keys.reduce(
        (a, key) => {
          a[key] = true;
          return a;
        },
        { ...acc }
      );
    }, {})
  );

  // with the `combineLatest` here we make sure to run the rest of the observable whenever either of those change
  public mainDataFiltered$: Observable<Record<string, unknown>> = combineLatest(
    [this.mainData$, this.excludedKeys$]
  ).pipe(
    map(([mainData, excludedKeys]) =>
      // we take the main data object and list all it's keys
      // we loop onto them using reduce and only add them into
      // the new object (passed as second argument of the reduce, to respect immutability)
      // IF they're not part of the excluded keys
      Object.keys(mainData).reduce((acc, key) => {
        if (!excludedKeys[key]) {
          acc[key] = mainData[key];
        }
        return acc;
      }, {})
    ),
    // finally, as we could subscribe to this variable from various locations at the same time and we don't want all that logic being run as many times as we've got subscribers, we use `shareReplay`
    // it lets us subscribe only once to it IF there's at least 1 subscription (`refCount: true`). Otherwise it'll complete. And if there's a new subscriber, we want the new subscriber to get the last value that was emitted before he joined so we do: `bufferSize: 1`
    shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })
  );

  public addFilter(filter$: Observable<Record<string, unknown>>): void {
    this.filters$$.next(filter$);
  }
}
```

You can have a live go at it on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-doqaxn?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

If this is not what you're looking for, please edit your post with the kind of API you'd like to have and I can probably help with the implementation behind the scenes.

Comment: That's clever. ;) Although I have to admit you lost me a little around the excludedKeys$ observable. I will have to step through that the debugger to understand it a little better. Very much appreciate the effort, at first glance it looks like it's on the right track!

Comment: Also, just to answer your question... there is no API behind this. It's just a continuous stream of data as the user progresses through the "stepper." The output of your code is what I would expect it to be I think, but I just want to make sure I understand how you got there. And at least for for the benefit of anybody else reading this question in the future, I would like to make sure that my question and your answer are in sync so as not to confuse anyone (myself included lol).

Comment: "That's clever. ;)". Thanks. Hopefully it's clever in a good way, not a too complicated one. I've edited my answer and added a lot of comments directly onto the code to explain what is going on. Let me know if it's clear or if there's anything that I should explain differently/more in depth

Comment: Also, how would you subscribe to the filtered data in the place where you called addFilter? i.e. My thought was that it would filter the data on the main stream, but sort of pluck it out and notify at the caller. Initially I was leaning towards something similar to what Aviad P suggested, using predicates. 

In any case, you've done plenty and I appreciate it, and I think I could take it from here, and extend your code to do that. However if you're feeling adventurous I would love to see your take on it!

Comment: Ok so this is where I ended up, obviously with some helpful inspiration from you @maxime1992:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xd8dz4?file=index.ts

After doing this with a predicate, I am keen on finding a way to do this by returning an observable from pluckRecord perhaps. Not sure, haven't played around with idea that too much yet.