# Rxjs - Collects all unprocessed values

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

I want to use `Subject` has an async task queue with concurrency = 1.

Gathering new tasks is faster than performaning those tasks so, as a performance optimization, I would like to process all un-processed tasks until now.

The following code goes over task by task:

```
this.tasks
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(async task => {
          await this.processTasks([task])
        }, 1),
      )
```

I would like to covert the above code to something similar to:

```
this.tasks
      .pipe(
        mergeMap___AllUnprocessedUntilNow(async tasks => {
          await this.processTasks(tasks)
        }, 1),
      )
```

- I can't use `bufferTime` or `bufferCount` because they will introduce additiol latency to every new task.

---

Actual Run Result:

```
* adding task 1 
* procssing task 1 (takes alot of time to perform it)
* meanwhile, adding more tasks: 2,3,4
* processed task 1
* procssing task 2
* processed task 2
* procssing task 3
* processed task 3
* procssing task 4
* processed task 4
```

Expected Run Result:

```
* adding task 1 
* procssing task 1 (takes alot of time to perform it)
* meanwhile, adding more tasks: 2,3,4
* processed task 1
* procssing task 2,3,4
* processed task 2,3,4
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood 100% your requirement, but if I did I think you're looking for higher order observables. You can take a look into what I believe would be a similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68753757/2398593

Comment: @maxime1992 I added actual/expected logs (I did not understand the Q and the A of the link you provided).

Comment: So basically you want to do those tasks 1 by 1? Just have a queue of async tasks that executes 1 after the other?

Comment: @maxime1992 I want to perform tasks in batches and if im reading slower than adding more tasks, i would like to get all tasks that were added until the next time I take more tasks. look at the examples.

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom operator that does this. Heads up, there are a few bits that make this more complicated than you might first think. On top of that, this is a bit over-engineered but it sounds like you can use this with the defaults to get what you want.

#### Custom RxJS Operator: bufferedExhaustMap

```ts
function bufferedExhaustMap<T, R>(
  project: (v: T[]) => ObservableInput<R>,
  minBufferLength = 0,
  minBufferCount = 1,
  concurrent = 1
): OperatorFunction<T, R> {

  function diffCounter(){
    const incOrDec = new Subject<boolean>();
    return {
      onAvailable: incOrDec.pipe(
        scan((acc, curr) => (curr ? ++acc : --acc), 0),
        startWith(0),
        shareReplay(1),
        first(count => count < concurrent),
        mapTo(true)
      ),
      start: () => incOrDec.next(true),
      end: () => incOrDec.next(false)
    };
  }

  return source => defer(() => {
    const projectCount = diffCounter();

    const shared = source.pipe(share());

    const nextBufferTime = () => forkJoin([
      shared.pipe(take(minBufferCount), delay(0)),
      timer(minBufferLength),
      projectCount.onAvailable
    ]);

    return shared.pipe(
      bufferWhen(nextBufferTime),
      delayWhen(() => projectCount.onAvailable),
      tap(projectCount.start),
      map(project),
      mergeMap(projected => from(projected).pipe(
        finalize(projectCount.end))
      )
    );
  });
}
```

#### Usage

Note, I've removed some superfluous promise/RxJS mingling as it's a code smell.

```ts
this.tasks.pipe(
  mergeMap___AllUnprocessedUntilNow(async tasks => {
    await this.processTasks(tasks)
  }, 1),
)
```

becomes

```ts
this.tasks.pipe(
  mergeMap___AllUnprocessedUntilNow(
    tasks => this.processTasks(tasks)
    , 1
  )
)
```

*(remember that all high-order RxJS operators will turn iterables and promises into observables for you. Otherwise you can use the `from` operator instead).*

Since `bufferedExhaustMap` has a default concurrency of 1, you can write this with the new operator as follows:

```ts
this.tasks.pipe(
  bufferedExhaustMap(
    tasks => this.processTasks(tasks)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a combination of [`buffer`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/buffer) and [`concatMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap), along with a little help from [`filter`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter) and [`tap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do).

The idea is to trigger the release of the buffer at the correct time.  In your case there are two occasions to release:

- When the first emission is received
- After work has been completed

```js
const release$ = new Subject<void>();
let releaseOnNextEmit = true;

const work$ = item$.pipe(
  tap(() => { 
    if(releaseOnNextEmit) setTimeout(() => release$.next(), 0);
  }),
  buffer(release$),
  tap(tasks => releaseOnNextEmit = tasks.length === 0),
  filter(tasks => tasks.length > 0),
  concatMap(tasks => processTasks(tasks)),
  tap(() => release$.next())
);
```

You can see we use a Subject to trigger the release of the buffer and a `releaseOnNextEmit` flag to indicate whether receiving an emission should trigger the buffer's release.

After the buffer emits, we set the flag accordingly:

- `true` when buffer is empty
- `false` when it is NOT empty

`filter` is used to prevent passing along empty arrays to `concatMap` (*buffer will emit empty array if the buffer is empty when its trigger emits*).

We use `concatMap` to execute the real work, then simply release the buffer afterwards.

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-69708928-atds3e?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) demo.

---

With all the `tap`s in there, this isn't super easy to follow, so it may be beneficial to put it into a custom operator:

```js
function bufferConcatMap<T, R>(project: (a: T[]) => ObservableInput<R>) {
  const release$ = new Subject<void>();
  let releaseOnNextEmit = true;

  return (source$: Observable<T>) => source$.pipe(
    tap(() => { 
      if(releaseOnNextEmit) setTimeout(() => release$.next(), 0);
    }),
    buffer(release$),
    tap(tasks => releaseOnNextEmit = tasks.length === 0),
    filter(tasks => tasks.length > 0),
    concatMap(project),
    tap(() => release$.next())
  );
}
```

```js
const work$ = item$.pipe(
  bufferConcatMap(tasks => processTasks(tasks))
);
```

Here's another [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-69708928?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100).